# Mysql POINT column for distance search

Tags: mysql, search, geolocation, geospatial, mariadb

yes i know this question ever asked plenty of time but all seems outdated from 2012, base of thoses question/ansewers ,
i tried to perform the classic search distance with column POINT
but i have some trouble unresolvable..

is normal my POINT column looks like this ?

```
0x00000000010100000085B1852007052040C0B2D2A414684840
```

Here is all my steps, i am not able to see whats wrong,
i did based from last stack questions/answers.

I use mariadb 10 with Heideisql gui.

i have 2 colums lat and lon ,
i created a geopoints POINT column,
populate geopoint like this:

```
 UPDATE  geoFRA 
SET     geopoints = GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT (', lon, ' ', lat, ')'))
```

After that my geopoints column looks like this :

```
  0x00000000010100000085B1852007052040C0B2D2A414684840
```

Then i try to perform the query in 2 maners , first try :

```
SET@lat = 48.88;
SET@lon = 2.34;

SELECT  *
FROM    geoFRA
WHERE   MBRContains(LineFromText(CONCAT(
        '('
        , @lon + 700 / ( 111.1 / cos(RADIANS(@lon)))
        , ' '
        , @lat + 700 / 111.1
        , ','
        , @lon - 700 / ( 111.1 / cos(RADIANS(@lat)))
        , ' '
        , @lat - 700 / 111.1 
        , ')' )
        ,geopoints)
```

and second try :

```
SET@lat = 48.88;
SET@lon = 2.34;
SET @kmRange = 172; -- = 50 Miles

SELECT *, (3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@lat - abs(`lat`)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(`lat`) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((lon - `lon`) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2)))) as distance
FROM    `geoFRA`
WHERE   MBRContains(LineString(Point(@lat + @kmRange / 111.1, @lon + @kmRange / (111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat)))), Point(@lat - @kmRange / 111.1, @lon - @kmRange / (111.1 / COS(RADIANS(@lat))))), `geopoints`)
Order By distance
```

I begin to think there is some mariadb incompatibility ?! or did i miss something?

thanks for any help..,
flau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE geoFRA (id int NOT NULL, geopoints point NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO geoFRA (id, geopoints) VALUES
(1, geomFromText('POINT(48 2)')),
(2, geomFromText('POINT(48 3)')),
(3, geomFromText('POINT(48.88 2.34)')),
(4, geomFromText('POINT(49 2)')),
(5, geomFromText('POINT(49 3)'));

SET @p=geomFromText('POINT(48.88 2.34)');
SELECT X(geopoints), Y(geopoints), asText(geopoints), ST_Distance(geopoints, @p) as d
FROM   geoFRA
ORDER BY d;
```

This returns the geopoints ordered by distance. Using geopoints without X(), Y() and asText() returns them in the Well-Known Binary (WKB) format: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html#gis-wkb-format